# Is it possible to combine 2 or more images defined on single variables?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I first reclassified an existing land use classification and wrote the corresponding new classes on a new variable. Therefore I would like to know whether it is possible in GEE to combine these variables and their images / data again.

```
var aoi = point.buffer(200000);
var igbpLandCoverVis = {
  min: 1.0,
  max: 17.0,
  palette: [
    '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203', '009900', 'c6b044', 'dcd159',
    'dade48', 'fbff13', 'b6ff05', '27ff87', 'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c',
    '69fff8', 'f9ffa4', '1c0dff'
  ],
};

var LC2001 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1/2001_01_01')
                .select(['LC_Type1'])
                .clip(aoi); 

print(LC2001)                  



Map.addLayer(LC2001,igbpLandCoverVis, "LandCover2001")

//Reklassifizierung Grassland
var Grassland2001 = LC2001
    .eq(10)
    .or(LC2001.eq(6))
    .or(LC2001.eq(7))
    .or(LC2001.eq(8))
    .or(LC2001.eq(9));
print(Grassland2001)

Map.addLayer(Grassland2001, [],"Grassland2001", false);


//Reklassifizierung Forest
var Forest2001 = LC2001
    .eq(1)
    .or(LC2001.eq(2))
    .or(LC2001.eq(3))
    .or(LC2001.eq(4))
    .or(LC2001.eq(5));
print(Forest2001)


Map.addLayer(Forest2001, {},"Forest2001", false);

//Reklassifizierung Wetlands
var Wetlands2001 = LC2001
    .eq(11)
    .or(LC2001.eq(11));

print(Wetlands2001)


Map.addLayer(Wetlands2001, {},"Wetlands2001", false); 

//Reklassifizierung Crop
var crop2001 = LC2001
    .eq(12)
    .or(LC2001.eq(14));

print(crop2001)


Map.addLayer(crop2001, {},"Crop2001", false);

//Reklassifizierung Settlements
var Settlements2001 = LC2001
    .eq(13);

print(Settlements2001)


Map.addLayer(Settlements2001, {},"Settlements2001", false);

//Reklassifizierung Desert
var Desert2001 = LC2001
    .eq(15)
    .or(LC2001.eq(16));
print(Desert2001)


Map.addLayer(Desert2001, {},"Desert2001", false);

//Reklassifizierung Water
var Water2001 = LC2001
    .eq(17);

print(Water2001)


Map.addLayer(Water2001, {},"Water2001", false);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`ee.Image.addBands`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.image.addbands) and [`ee.Image.rename`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.image.rename).

`addBands` lets you create an image which has the bands from two different images, and in order to give them useful names you will want to `rename` them first since in your current situation, every band's name is `'LC_Type1'`.

```
var everything = LC2001
    .addBands(Grassland2001.rename('Grassland'))        
    .addBands(Forest2001.rename('Forest'))
    .addBands(Wetlands2001.rename('Wetlands'))
    .addBands(crop2001.rename('Crop'))
    .addBands(Settlements2001.rename('Settlements'))
    .addBands(Desert2001.rename('Desert'))
    .addBands(Water2001.rename('Water'));
```

This particular structure might not be what you need, but hopefully it illustrates the available operations.

Comment: Also see the `ee.Image.cat()` [function](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.image.cat). E.g., `ee.Image.cat(img1, img2, img3).rename(['b1', 'b2', 'b3'])`.

Answer (score 0):

thank u for ur help!
Your solution could definitely be helpful.
Do you know if there is also a possibility to combine the different tapes back into a tape so that a coloring like the original data set is possible?